# Sensiolabs Insight : Twig templates should not contain business logic

Tags: symfony, twig

I am actually running Sensiolabs Insight analysis on my Symfony 2.8 project.

I have a major issue with some of my Twig templates:

> Twig templates should not contain business logic

The associated message is always the same :

> Template too complex, depth of 10 is reached but only 5 is allowed.

For example this happens with the following template :

```twig
{% extends "FBNGuideBundle::layout.html.twig" %}

{% block title %}
  {{ 'fbn.guide.page_title.bookmarks'|trans }}
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}

  <div id="bookmarks" data-bookmark-ids="{{bookmarkIds|json_encode()}}">

    {% if (restaurants|length > 0) %}

      <div class="restaurants">
        <h3>MES RESTOS</h3>
        {% for bookmark in restaurants %}
          <div class="bookmark" id="{{'bookmark-' ~ bookmark.id}}">
            <a href="{{ path('fbn_guide_restaurants', {'slug': bookmark.restaurant.slug} ) }}">{{ bookmark.restaurant.name }}</a>
            <br>
            <br>
            <button>SUPPRIMER DES FAVORIS</button>      
            <br>
            <hr>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
      </div>

    {% endif %}

  </div>

{% endblock %}
```

I tried to include in a separated file the code contained inside `<div id="bookmarks"></div>` and the depth has been reduced, but it is not a solution. I suppose that the problem is the access to some  properties through several objects using getters (i.e `bookmark.restaurant.slug)`.

I have a free plan so I am not able to access the documentation related to this warning. Anyone knows how to solve the problem ?

Thanks.

Comment: It it's because you are using bookmark.restaurant.slug this warning is stupid because in this case that mean that data were indeed "prepared" in your controller and just access it. I guess that's a limitation of such static analysis tools.

Comment: @COil I agree with you, data are prepared at controller level and before that at doctrine repository level (join). However, I forked the [Symfony demo repo](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-demo) and ran an Insight analysis. I didn't get this warning even if, for example, in this application you find in a template something like : **`{% for comment in post.comments %} ... {{ comment.author.fullName }} ... {% endfor %}`**

Comment: @COil You were right, I just contacted the Insight support and here is the answer : "For me, you template is perfect ;) It looks like there is a bug in our algorithm. I will open a new ticket in our internal bug tracker.
In the meantime, you can safely ignore this violation."

Comment: @Cruz have you got some news about this ticket?

Answer (score -2):

When you have too much logic in the view, you can put it in a custom Twig Extension. An advantage is that you don't need to duplicate the html if you are reusing that part in another page and of course, the code is more clear :)
In your case, you can write a new Twig Extension that renders all the bookmarks.

If you didn't build somethng similar till now, you can read about it here http://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html

Comment: I don't think that Twig extensions are designed for this purpose. See my last comment above.

Comment: No, there is no need for an extension, there isn't business logic in the template.

Comment: I didn't said that they are designed for this purpose. It was just an alternative for a better separation of the code and getting rid of that warning.

Comment: @Daniella No worry :)